# Setting sticky cookie in scrapy

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy

The website I am scraping has javascript that sets a cookie and checks it in the backend to make sure js is enabled. Extracting the cookie from the html code is simple enough, but then setting it seems to be a problem in scrapy. So my code is:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider

class TestSpider(InitSpider):
    ...
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('products/./index\.html', )), callback='parse_page'),)

    def init_request(self):
        return Request(url = self.init_url, callback=self.parse_js)

    def parse_js(self, response):
        match = re.search('setCookie\(\'(.+?)\',\s*?\'(.+?)\',', response.body, re.M)
        if match:
            cookie = match.group(1)
            value = match.group(2)
        else:
            raise BaseException("Did not find the cookie", response.body)
        return Request(url=self.test_page, callback=self.check_test_page, cookies={cookie:value})

    def check_test_page(self, response):
        if 'Welcome' in response.body:
            self.initialized()

    def parse_page(self, response):
        scraping....
```

I can see that the content is available in `check_test_page`, the cookie works perfectly. But it never even gets to `parse_page` since CrawlSpider without the right cookie doesn't see any links. Is there a way to set a cookie for the duration of the scraping session? Or do I have to use BaseSpider and add the cookie to every request manually?

A less desirable alternative would be to set the cookie (the value seems to never change) through scrapy configuration files somehow. Is that possible?

Comment: Scrapy passes all cookies around by default: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-manage-cookies-automatically

Comment: that's the cookies set by the server. As far as I can see there's no way to add a permanent cookie from the client (scrapy). It has to be done for each Request separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that InitSpider is a BaseSpider. So it looks like 1) there's no way to use CrawlSpider in this situation 2) there's no way to set a sticky cookie

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `InitSpider` before.

Looking at the code in `scrapy.contrib.spiders.init.InitSpider` i see:

```
def initialized(self, response=None):
    """This method must be set as the callback of your last initialization
    request. See self.init_request() docstring for more info.
    """
    self._init_complete = True
    reqs = self._postinit_reqs[:]
    del self._postinit_reqs
    return reqs

def init_request(self):
    """This function should return one initialization request, with the
    self.initialized method as callback. When the self.initialized method
    is called this spider is considered initialized. If you need to perform
    several requests for initializing your spider, you can do so by using
    different callbacks. The only requirement is that the final callback
    (of the last initialization request) must be self.initialized. 

    The default implementation calls self.initialized immediately, and
    means that no initialization is needed. This method should be
    overridden only when you need to perform requests to initialize your
    spider
    """
    return self.initialized()
```

You wrote:

> I can see that the content is available in `check_test_page`, the cookie
>   works perfectly. But it never even gets to `parse_page` since
>   `CrawlSpider` without the right cookie doesn't see any links.

I think `parse_page` is not called because you didn't make a Request with `self.initialized` as the callback.

I think this should work:

```
def check_test_page(self, response):
    if 'Welcome' in response.body:
        return self.initialized()
```

Comment: You are right, I've had a look at the source code myself. But it turned out that InitSpider is a BaseSpider anyway. So it looks like 1) there's no way to use CrawlSpider in this situation 2) there's no way to set a sticky cookie