# Does the scrapy BaseSpider class has "rules" option or not

Tags: python, scrapy

I have seen plenty of question on SO where people are asking about when they inherit from BaseSpider
or InitSpider.

[Setting sticky cookie in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949667/setting-sticky-cookie-in-scrapy)

```
class TestSpider(InitSpider):
    ...
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('products/./index\.html', )), callback='parse_page'),)

    def init_request(self):
        return Request(url = self.init_url, callback=self.parse_js)
```

Now i have seen that BaseSPider don't have any "rules" option but peole are still writing that.

I want to know whether i am wrong or not

I haven't seen any senior member mentioning this in the question as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the source code for the different types of spider, we can conclude that the following is true.

Implements rules:

- [CrawlSpider](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py) (the Rule class is defined from lines 17 to 28 and added as a data member to the CrawlSpider class on line 32)

Does not implement rules:

- [BaseSpider](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spider.py)
- [InitSpider](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/init.py)
- [XMLFeedSpider](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/feed.py)

If you're not convinced about this because of all the examples where someone has defined a rule in spiders other than CrawlSpider, you could test this out by creating a rule that refers to `callback1` and have a statement in `callback1` along the lines of:

`print "We're in callback1 so the rule must work"`

If you see that statement when you run the non-CrawlSpider spider then you know that rules are implemented.